# Understanding solution of a particular ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Reading some class notes I came across the following diferential equation, for $k=1,2,3$...
\begin{equation}
\frac{d^{2}}{d t^{2}} \alpha_{k}(t)+k^{4} \pi^{4} \alpha_{k}(t)=\beta_{k} h^{\prime \prime}(t), \quad \alpha_{k}(0)=0, \alpha_{k}^{\prime}(0)=0
\end{equation}
where $\beta_{k}$ is just a function depending on $k$. So, the solution given is the following
\begin{equation}
\alpha_{k}(t)=\beta_{k} h_{1}(t)+\int_{0}^{t} \frac{ i\beta_{k}}{2} k^{2} \pi^{2}\left(e^{i k^{2} \pi^{2}(t-\tau)}-e^{-i k^{2} \pi^{2}(t-\tau)}\right) h(\tau) d \tau
\end{equation}
which I am having a lot of trouble trying to understant how to get this. It seems that it cannot be parameters variation since the homogeneous ODE has zero solution, so theres no wronskian in this case (or am i missing something). Also, trying to see if the solution satisfy the equation does not seems to be straightforward which makes things trickier for me.

Any hint would be really helpfull.

Thank you in advance

Comment: "since the homogeneous ODE has zero solution" ofcourse you can use variations of parameters.  The bases for the homogeneous solution are present. Here is [a solution on the internet.](https://12000.org/tmp/02182022/foo_5.pdf)

Comment: @Nasser I was not expecting an answer like that, thank you for taking the time.